# Why is $\lambda x.\lambda y.xy$ not reducible to $\lambda x.x$?

Tags: lambda-calculus

(**NB:** λ-calculus n00b here!)

I derive the following:
$$
\lambda x.\lambda y.xy \equiv \lambda x.(\lambda y.xy) \equiv \lambda x.x
$$

To check myself, I tried to reduce the same expression with several online "λ-calculus calculators" (e.g. the [λ Calculus Calculator](https://lambdacalc.io) or [Lambda Calculator](http://www.cburch.com/lambda/)), and, to my surprise, they all agree that the original expression ($\lambda x.\lambda y.xy$) is already in normal form (and therefore, no further reductions are possible).

Where does my derivation go wrong?

My derivation consists of two "moves": (1) "insertion of parentheses" (just to make the evaluation order explicit), and (2) one reduction, namely $\lambda y.xy \equiv x$.  The latter is an instance of what the book I am following<sup>1</sup> calls an "η-reduction."  I figure that one of these two moves must be wrong, but I can't see how.

(FWIW, I do agree with these online calculators that the similar-looking expression $\lambda x.\lambda y.yx$ is in normal form.)

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> *Denotational Semantics: The Scott-Strachey Approach to Programming Language Theory* (1977) by Joseph E. Stoy.</sup>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

'Normal form' typically means '$\beta$ normal form' and not '$\beta\eta$ normal form', so your $\eta$-reduction step is not allowed by the normal form calculators.